# jQuery AJAX not hitting ASP.NET Web Service when passing parameters

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, ajax, web-services

JavaScript:

```
 var paramStr =  $('#id1').val() + '|' + $('#id2').val() + '|' +  $('#id3').val();
    paramStr = '{"searchCriteria": "' + paramStr + '"}';

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/MyService.asmx/MyWebMethod",
      data: paramStr,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {

      }
    });
```

VB.NET:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class LogisticsMainMenuService
  Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

      <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
      <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
      Public Function MyWebMethod(ByVal searchCriteria As String) As String
        Dim dummy as Integer = 1
        .
        .
        Return someResult
      End Function
End Class
```

I put a break point inside MyWebMethod.  When I invoke this call on the page, the break point never gets hit.  It works fine when I remove all parameters from MyWebMethod's signature and pass in '{}' from JS as parameters.  Once I try to pass in a string parameter, it stops working.

Comment: i don't know if this matters, but isn't web services SOAP based, passing in request parameters is only going to change the URL to: /MyService.asmx/MyWebMethod?{"searchCriteria": "1|2|3"} which is not going to work very well

Comment: @Bob  I looked over about 5 different examples, they all suggest doing it this way.  I've worked with .NET MVC before.  This (or similar) would be the way to do it in MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! After seriously banging my head on the keyboard and picking up some extra FireBug skills, I got my problem solved.

url: "/MyService.asmx/MyWebMethod",

should be

url: "MyService.asmx/MyWebMethod",

without the first "/".
Apparently, the first call is going to www.mysite.com/MyService.asmx as oppose www.mysite.com/dir/MyService.asmx even if making the call from within /dir... which I did.
Happy AJAXing, everybody!